# Problems with upload waypoints to GPS unit

Tags: qgis, gpsbabel

How can I upload waypoints from QGIS to my Garmin GPSmap 62 by using GPS Tools in plugins? I only manage to do it with an older Garmin GPS.

Comment: Can you expand a lot more on your question and perhaps provide some screenshots, error messages, etc to be able to assist you?

Comment: Agree, please add error message, platform, qgis version, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you are able to download data, in any case this link describes how to connect a garmin usb gps in Qgis

http://nickmcw.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/quantum-gis-using-a-usb-gps-device/

As everyone else has told you, a little bit of more information could be useful in order to help you.....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague as commented above, but I have been successful at getting waypoints (a qgis layer) into my magellan triton using the following process. I obtained the qgis plugin "PostGPS2gpx". This converts a selected qgis layer into a gpx file which can then be loaded into into your handheld gps with the software that came with your device rather than trying to cable directly to qgis.